# Xamarin Button Grid cutts text on small devices

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grid with buttons which display the numbers from 1 to 9 cause i want to make an calculator.
On big devices with about 2000 px height the grid shows the numbers on the button.
But when I test in on a small device 480x320 the buttons cut the text off.

I already adjusted also the font when I use a small device:

```
if(width<400)
                FontSizeInputButtons = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Button))/2;
                else
                FontSizeInputButtons = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Button));
```

I don't now how to solve this issue to simply display the numbers also on small devices:

[image]

On my S10 it works:

[image]

Comment: can you show us the xaml for the grid?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#spans) is a official sample project about calculator, you can download it and have a try.